# Собеседование JavaEE junior

Tags: java-ee

Добрый день!
Что обычно спрашивают на сабже? Буду благодарен за ссылки на материалы и комментарии.
PS в сети есть книжки по J2EE, мне кажется, это устарелый материал и не валидный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

любое собеседование разделяйте на такие части:

- проверка вменяемости (часто делается не техническим специалистом)
- проверка базовых алгоритмов (без привязки к какому то языку программирования, многие валятся именно здесь)
- java core
- разное, в зависимости от того, чем занимается компания - tomcat, hibernate, apache, библиотеки логгирования.

у многих компаний есть свои любимые задачи. Им не важен результат решения, им важен "процесс решения".